# How to delete duplicate records in from multiple tables in SQL oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

in the image, these are the records in my tables from two different tables which are linked together through the "CUSTABN". As the records from these tables are duplicated, so I want to delete all the duplicate records.

[Records from multiple tables (Customer & Invoice)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSWIa.png)

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: want to delete duplicates or want to select distinct values from 2 tables ?

Comment: I want to delete the duplicate records from two tables that is linked together.
the tables is in the link on top of this page (Records from multiple tables (Customer & Invoice))

Comment: are you sure the data are duplicated and are not the result of a join ?... in this case you need a select distinct and not a delete ..

Comment: that records are combination of both tables. but is it possible to delete?

Answer (score 1):

If your tables are related with foreign key field "CUSTABN", I think this is what you want :

```
DELETE T1, T2 FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.CUSTABN = T2.CUSTABN WHERE ...
```

Comment: would you please make a clear query because am stuck on how to delete records from two related tables

Comment: You can use this query without any condition ( without WHERE clause ) and it will delete all records returned from join ( duplicate records ), but first test it on two test table to ensure that I correctly discovered what you want !